# What are the scoping rules for subsequent calls to dlopen?

Tags: dynamic-linking, dlopen, dlsym

Suppose I have an executable that `dlopen`s **libfirst.so** with `RTLD_LOCAL` which then `dlopen`s `libsecond.so` with `RTLD_GLOBAL`. Should the symbols from **libsecond.so** now be directly available (i.e., without `dlsym`) in (1) only **libfirst.so** or (2) in both **libfirst.so** and the executable?

From the [manpage on `dlopen`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html)

> RTLD_GLOBAL: The symbols defined by this shared object will be made available for symbol resolution of subsequently loaded shared objects.

This sounds like the symbols from **libsecond.so** are *not* made available to either the executable or **libfirst.so** (except via `dlsym`). Is this correct?

Comment: I think part of my misunderstanding is related to what is exactly meant by "subsequently" in the manpage. I am now thinking that what is being said here is simply that since the symbols in the main executable have already been resolved, updating the symbol table has no effect on those resolutions...

Comment: Maybe you wish to ask if the unresolved symbols of the already loaded components could become resolved during dlopen. The answer is 'no'.

Comment: Since libfirst.so and the executable have already been successfully loaded, they have no unresolved symbols to potentially be resolved by libsecond.so.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond -- that allows you to *create* objects with unresolved symbols -- but those symbols must be resolved when the object is *loaded* or the load will fail.

Comment: @ChrisDodd for example, in yugr's answer here both `foo` and `bar` are unresolved symbols in the main executable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should the symbols from libsecond.so now be directly available (i.e., without dlsym) in (1) only libfirst.so or (2) in both libfirst.so and the executable?

I don't think you understand what "directly available" means in this context.

Suppose `libsecond.so` defines `second()`. That symbol is not available in either `libfirst.so` or the main `a.out` (*obviously* -- they have been already loaded *before* `libsecond.so` was brought in).

But if you now load (via `dlopen()`) `libthird.so`, and if that library has `second()` as an unresolved symbol (in other words, `libthird.so` has a *direct* dependency on `second()`), the load of `libthird.so` would succeed if `libsecond.so` was loaded with `RTLD_GLOBAL`, but would fail (with *unresolved* `second()`) if `libsecond.so` was loaded with `RTLD_LOCAL`.

Comment: Just to check my understanding: if both `a.out` and `libsecond.so` defined a function `foo` with the same signature and `libsecond.so` was loaded with `RTLD_GLOBAL`, and this function was used in both `libfirst.so` and `libthird.so`, `libfirst.so` would resolve `foo` exactly once as the function in `a.out` and `libthird.so` would resolve `foo` as the function in `libsecond.so`, right?

Answer (score 1):

Symbols will be visible in *both* executable and libfirst.

Take this simple example in which executable tries to access symbol from `libsecond.so` *after* `libsecond.so` is loaded.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef FIRST
void foo() { dlopen("./libsecond.so", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL); }
#elif defined SECOND
void bar() { printf("Hello from libsecond\n"); }
#else
extern void foo();
extern void bar();

int main() {
  dlopen("./libfirst.so", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL);
  foo();
  bar();
  return 0;
}
#endif
```

When run, the call to `bar()` in main executable is successfully executed:

```
$ gcc -fuse-ld=lld -shared -fPIC -DFIRST prog.c -o libfirst.so
$ gcc -fuse-ld=lld -shared -fPIC -DSECOND prog.c -o libsecond.so
$ gcc -fuse-ld=lld -Wl,-z,lazy -Wl,-z,undefs prog.c
$ ./a.out
Hello from libsecond
```

Interestingly this example does not link with GNU ld (it fails to generate correct relocations for `foo` and `bar` in executable).